# Implementing Progress bar using WPF with MVVM pattern (Using BackgroundWorker)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, progress-bar, backgroundworker

### Note: This code works now. I have fixed some stupid mistake and I have also revised code as Steve Greatrex pointed out.

Original Posting LINK [How to implement a progress bar using the MVVM pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520359/how-to-implement-a-progress-bar-using-the-mvvm-pattern/3520445#3520445)

### ProgressbarSampleView.xaml

```
  <UserControl x:Class="MyProject.ProgressbarSampleView"
               xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
               Height="718" Width="1024">

  <ProgressBar Grid.Row="1" 
                 Value="{Binding CurrentProgress, Mode=OneWay}" 
                 Visibility="{Binding ProgressVisibility}" 
                 Margin="22,0,25,0" />

  <Button   Grid.Row="2"
            Content="Start Now"  
            Height="30" 
            Width="80" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="22,4,0,0" 
            Name="btnStartNow" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Command="{Binding Path=InstigateWorkCommand}" 
            />
  </UserControl>
```

### ProggressbarSampleViewModel.cs

```cs
  namespace MyProject
  {
   public class ProggressbarSampleViewModel: ViewModelBase
   {
     private readonly BackgroundWorker worker; 
     private readonly ICommand instigateWorkCommand;

     public ProggressbarSampleViewModel()
     {
        this.instigateWorkCommand = new 
                      RelayCommand(o => this.worker.RunWorkerAsync(), o => !this.worker.IsBusy);
        this.worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        this.worker.DoWork += this.DoWork;
        this.worker.ProgressChanged += this.ProgressChanged;
    }


    public ICommand InstigateWorkCommand
    {
        get { return this.instigateWorkCommand; }
    }

    private int _currentProgress;
    public int CurrentProgress
    {
        get { return this._currentProgress; }
        private set
        {
            if (this._currentProgress != value)
            {
                this._currentProgress = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentProgress"); 
            }
        }
     }

     private void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
     {
        this.CurrentProgress = e.ProgressPercentage;
     }

    private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // do time-consuming work here, calling ReportProgress as and when you can   
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            _currentProgress = i;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentProgress");
        }
    }

  }
```

Comment: after writing such string:" this.instigateWorkCommand = new RelayCommand(o => this.worker.RunWorkerAsync, o => !this.worker.IsBusy);" . VS2010 throws an error: "delegate 'system.action' does not take 1 arguments". Could you tell how to get over it? What version of .Net Framework do you use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `StartNowCommand` never invokes the `BackgroundWorker` - it just synchronously executes the `DoStartNow` method on the UI thread.  Based on this, I'd guess that when you click on the button linked to the `StartNow` command you see your UI freeze up..?

You should be binding your button to the `InstigateWorkCommand` which actually runs `BackgroundWorker` code asynchronously.

In this implementation I don't think you would need the `StartNowCommand` at all.  I also don't see the `DoWork` event handler anywhere in your view  model, so I'm assuming that it just calls `DoStartNow`