# implementing progress bar in wpf window with viewmodel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have wpf window (`MainWindow`.cs) which has button and progress bar.

Button is bound to command inside my viewmodel

```
<Button Command="{Binding StartMyWork}" Content="Run" Width="200" Height="50"/>
```

progress bar is bound to CurrentProgress property also in viewmodel

```
<ProgressBar Value="{Binding CurrentProgress, Mode=OneWay}"  Width="400"/>
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
private ICommand _StartMyWork;
public ICommand StartMyWork;
{ 
    get {
         if (_StartMyWork == null) {
                _StartMyWork = new RelayCommand(
                       x => this.DoSomeDummyWork(this.MySelectedComboValue)
                );
          }
          return _StartMyWork;
     }
}

private void DoSomeDummyWork(string mySelectedComboProp)
{
    // here I want to simulate some work
    // and make ui responsive and introduce progressbar    
}
```

I was thinking using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3520436/1765862)

So I added in the same viewmodel

```
private ICommand _InstigateWorkCommand;
private double _CurrentProgress;
private BackgroundWorker _Worker;

private void DoSomeDummyWork(string mySelectedComboProp)
{
    // here I want to simulate some work
    // and make ui responsive and introduce progressbar
     _InstigateWorkCommand = new RelayCommand(x => _Worker.RunWorkerAsync(),  x => !_Worker.IsBusy);
     _Worker = new BackgroundWorker();
     _Worker.DoWork += DoWork;
     _Worker.ProgressChanged += this.ProgressChanged;   
}

private void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    _CurrentProgress = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

public double CurrentProgress
{
    get { return _CurrentProgress; }
    private set {
         if (_CurrentProgress != value){
            _CurrentProgress = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentProgress");
         }
    }
}

private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       Thread.Sleep(1000);
       _CurrentProgress = i;
   }
}

private void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
   _CurrentProgress = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

Where I'm wrong in implementing progress bar, I set breakpoint in 
DoWork method which is never hitted, although first command StartMyWork works as expected.

Comment: Add _Worker.RunWorkerAsync(), you never call _Worker.ReportProgress(value) so ProgressChanged will never be invoked.

Comment: please can you be specific, I already have _Worker.RunWorkerAsync(), .. inside DoSomeDummyWork method.

Comment: I dont know why you're being so rude, he's right, it's getting called in his lamba right at the top of DoSomeDummywork in the view model, and he's got no edits on the question.

Comment: I think he just kept it in the InstigateWork relaycommand by mistake.

Comment: `if _StartMyWork;== null)` isn't going to compile. Please post correct code to avoid all sorts of confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, 
remove your second command ICommand _InstigateWorkCommand; you dont need it, at least for now, it just makes you confuse.

Inside your method *(DoSomeDummyWork)* which first command executes remove those lambda expression line 
*_InstigateWorkCommand = new RelayCommand(x => _Worker.RunWorkerAsync(),  x => !_Worker.IsBusy);*
and put this

```
 _Worker = new BackgroundWorker();
 _Worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
 _Worker.DoWork += DoWork;                        
 _Worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
_Worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

also DoWork method should look like this

```
private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    _Worker.ReportProgress(i*(100/10));          
  }            
}

private void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    _CurrentProgress = e.ProgressPercentage;
    OnPropertyChanged("CurrentProgress");
}
```

Also you should now add method which will be called once iteration is completed

```
void workerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Complete!");
}
```

and wire this method

```
_Worker.RunWorkerCompleted += 
      new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(workerCompleted);
```

*Just to mention that *`RunWorkerCompleted`* event fires, no matter how the bg. thread completed - wheter it completed normally or an exception is thrown (cancel action). Although if you shut down application while the bg. worker running the application will immediatly exit without waiting bg. thread to complete.*

Comment: key line is     OnPropertyChanged("CurrentProgress") i believe, what is the  difference between having in the progresschanged function vs having like original questions in the property constructor. obviously your one works and other one doesnt work but why? does it not trigger when property changes?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to activate your _InstigateWorkCommand with some kind of interaction or you'll never kick off the actual update. If you want to instead stop using _InstigateWorkCommand and just kick it off when you click the button bound to StartMyWork, than you'll need to move the RunWorkerAsync code up a level out of the RelayCommand binding.

Ex:

```
private void DoSomeDummyWork(string mySelectedComboProp)
{
    // here I want to simulate some work
    // and make ui responsive and introduce progressbar
     _Worker = new BackgroundWorker();
     _Worker.DoWork += DoWork;
     _Worker.ProgressChanged += this.ProgressChanged; 
     _Worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, not full answer. As Maximus said, add `_Worker.RunWorkerAsync()` to the end of your `DoSomeDummyWork` method. Then:

```
private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       Thread.Sleep(1000);
       _CurrentProgress = i;
   }
}
```

Not `_CurrentProgress`, but `CurrentProgress`. It will notify your ProgressBar about changes.

Comment: He already set up the runworkerasync in a relay command at the top of his viewmodel.

Comment: As I understand, if he retained old command, new would not be called. If he changed main command to this, whole DoSomeDummyWork would not be executed