# Progress-bar MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am having a little bit of trouble getting a `ProgressBar` to work. When I start it up, nothing happens and I can't see why?

I thought that this would start the task `worker.RunWorkerAsync();`

The below example should be able to be copied and pasted into a new solution and be run for testing if needed.

The XAML,

```
<Grid Margin="20">
    <ProgressBar 
        Height="60"
        Minimum="0" 
        Maximum="100"
        Value="{Binding Progress, Mode=OneWay}" 
        Visibility="{Binding ProgressVisibility}"/>
</Grid>
```

My code,

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ProggressbarViewModel PsVm { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PsVm = new ProggressbarViewModel();
    }

    public class ProggressbarViewModel
    {
        public ProggressbarViewModel()
        {
            var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.DoWork += DoWork;
            worker.ProgressChanged += ProgressChanged;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private int _progress;

        public int Progress
        {
            get { return _progress; }
            set
            {
                if (_progress == value) return;
                _progress = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                _progress = i;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Progress = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: The question is is similar possibly a duplicate in that sense, however the linked answer did not solve my problem, like it states in the Duplicate banner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement a progress bar using the MVVM pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520359/how-to-implement-a-progress-bar-using-the-mvvm-pattern)

Comment: @Clint, yes I saw that thread. Does not help me much , as I don't know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're not explicitly indicating source object for your bindings (by means of `Binding.Source` or `Binding.RelativeSource` properties), the framework uses (possibly inherited) value of `DataContext` of the target object as the source. The problem is that you don't assign your view-model to the `DataContext` property of any control. Thus, the source for the bindings resolves to `null` and nothing is showing on your progress bar.

To resolve your issue you should assign your view model to the `DataContext` of your `MainWindow`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    PsVm = new ProggressbarViewModel();
    DataContext = PsVm;
}
```

If however you're planning on using different `DataContext` for your window, you can bind `DataContext` of `ProgressBar`:

```
<ProgressBar
    DataContext="{Binding Path=PsVm,
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:MainWindow}}"
    (...) />
```

You could also modify particular bindings by prepending `PsVm.` to the value of `Path` and using `RelativeSource`, e.g.:

```
 Value="{Binding Path=PsVm.Progress,
                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:MainWindow},
                 Mode=OneWay}"
```

In that case however you'd have to modify each binding, so previous solutions are quicker and/or simpler.

As a side note, you might also want to change the way you're reporting progress - note that `OnPropertyChanged` in your `DoWork` method is **not** called from UI thread. The proper way to do it would be:

```
private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        worker.ReportProgress(i); //This will raise BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged
    }
}
```

Also, in order to support progress reporting, you should set `WorkerReportsProgress` to `true` on your worker, e.g.:

```
var worker = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerReportsProgress = true };
```

Comment: I am going to mark this as solved and UV, due to everything working in the code. It seems I have Data-context issue I need to sort out.

Comment: Thanks Grx70, I got it working thanks to your help. The DataContext issue is solved. Cheers.